# continuation error while declaring the state variable

Tags: apex

I had written one method and call back method for continuation....

```
global class MyWrapper {
    public static object state{get;set;}
    public String Request { get; set; }
    public String Variable1 { get; set; }
    public String Variable2 { get; set; }

    global MyWrapper(String req, String var1, String var2) {
        Request = req;
        Variable1 = var1;
        Variable2 = var2;
    }

    //continuation method
    @RemoteAction
    global static somemehod(string par1,id par2,boolean par3){

       continuation.state = assgininment;
    }

    //call back method
    public static object(object state){
    }
}
```

In the above line i am getting an error continuation:

> state does not exist.

when i tried declaring the state variable globally , in call back method it is showing an error like duplicate variable state.any suggestions how to resolve it.???

Comment: Can you show your params in method? Where declared Contination instance variable?

Comment: Your code doesn't look much like the example in the [Continuation Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Continuation.htm) documentation. And I can imagine static fields and fields declared to be of type `Object` not being preserved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate an instance of the `Continuation` class in order to assign to the state, because it is an instance variable, not a static variable of the `Continuation` class - see this example from [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Continuation.htm) (I wish it showed them actually declaring `Continuation continuationInstance = new Continuation()`):

```
// Declare inner class to hold state info
private class StateInfo {
    String msg { get; set; }
    List<String> urls  { get; set; }
    StateInfo(String msg, List<String> urls) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.urls = urls;
    }
}

// Then in the action method, set state for the continuation
continuationInstance.state = new StateInfo('Some state data', urls);
```

The error you are seeing is the parser interpreting `Continuation.state` as an attempt to reference a static variable `state` in the `Continuation` class, which does not exist.